# XCode/Objective-C: Simultaneous animations for instances of UIView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview

I have two `IBOutlet` variables connected to two instances of `UIView` in Interface Builder, called `blankView` and `fadedBGView` in my `ViewController`.

How can I set up this code so that the `blankView` instance will fade into `fadedBGView`, using the `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` transition, and the two `UIViews` can simultaneously transform (move) from their current position (they have equal positions) to 0,0?

What's happening is the fade occurs, and then the `fadedBGView` view abruptly moves to 0,0.

In other words, I'd like to have the first `UIView` fade into the second, while simultaneously moving up the screen.

Hopefully this is clear enough to answer.
Best...SL

```
[UIView transitionFromView:blankView
                    toView:fadedBGView
                    duration:1.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [blankView removeFromSuperview];
                    }];

[UIView commitAnimations];

CGRect frame = fadedBGView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    NSLog(@"UIView Transition/Move Called");
    fadedBGView.frame = frame;
}];
```

Comment: Which versions of iOS do you need to support?

Comment: Haven't really thought about it...how's perhaps iOS4 and up? Just a guess, whatever you'd recommend I suppose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 4 and newer provides block-based animations, which your code is already using:

```
+[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:];
+[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:];
```

Within the animation block, you can set multiple destination values. See [Apple's UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) for a reference to the animatable properties. So within one block, you can modify frames, and alpha (transparency) values of views. I'm not sure how the cross dissolve animation works, but if it's simply one view going from 0 to 1, and another view going from 1 to 0, that's easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks bud, changed the alpha value within one block. Eliminated the need for the first instance of UIView. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
```

use

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
```

`UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` option allows additional animations during transition. Make sure your `fadedBGView` has correct starting frame.